# Facing executor heartbeat timed out while trying to read 5 Excel files parallelly in Spark

Tags: scala, apache-spark, azure-databricks

I am trying to read list of Excel files in a folder using DataBricks (Spark Scala).
I am facing below error.

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 16) (10.65.2.4 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 128422 ms

When i try to iterate through a for loop and get the count Individually it is working fine. I have also tried union all of them in the same for loop and took count outside the loop and was facing same issue.

Below is the code:

```
val fileList = dbutils.fs.ls("/mnt/raw/home/")
var fileDetailsList:Seq[String] = Seq.empty[String]
for(file <- fileList)
{
    if(!file.name.endsWith("/") && file.name.matches("^[A-Za-z0-9-_]+(_ADHERENCE_)([0-9]{4}(0[1-9]|1[012])(0[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[01]))(.xlsx)$") )   
    {
      fileDetailsList = fileDetailsList ++ Seq(file.path)
    }
}
print(fileDetailsList)
var adhTemp = spark.createDataFrame(sc.emptyRDD[Row], adhSchema)
adhTemp = spark.read.format("excel").schema(adhSchema).option("maxByteArraySize", 2100000000).option("header", "true").load(fileDetailsList:_*)
adhTemp.count
```

Answer (score 0):

> Job aborted due to stage failure: Task 2 in stage 7.0 failed 4 times, most recent failure: Lost task 2.3 in stage 7.0 (TID 16) (10.65.2.4 executor 3): ExecutorLostFailure (executor 3 exited caused by one of the running tasks) Reason: Executor heartbeat timed out after 128422 ms

This error occurs when we are dealing with large data and it times out the execution because of longer execution time.

In your case, it is running fine when reading individual files and giving this error when only trying to read multiple files at a time. It might be the reason for it that it is reading large data while combining the files.

So, reading the files individually can be the work around here. Update your code like below sample using `union`.

```
%scala
import  scala.collection.mutable.MutableList
import  org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
//data is a mount point
val  folder_path = "/mnt/data"

// Use filter on file path ends with .xlsx to get a list of excel files from dbutils.fs.ls
val  files_list = dbutils.fs.ls(folder_path).filter(file  => file.name.endsWith(".xlsx"))

// Read dataframe from each excel file and make a list
val  dfs: Seq[DataFrame] = excelFiles.map { file =>
spark.read
.format("com.crealytics.spark.excel")
.option("header", "true")
.load(file.path)
}

// Union them
val  res_df = dfs.reduce(_ union _)
println("count is: "+res_df.count)
res_df.show()
```

**My Sample result with 3 Excel files:**

[image]